# Controlling container margin in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble coding up the CSS to control the right page margin as I make a page wider and narrower. See: http://cosi236b.courses.salas.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

As I widen the page there is always a vertical margin on the right edge of the page. It shrinks or grows as I resize the page, but it never gets as narrow as I want it to. As it is there's a lot of wasted space.

I am having trouble changing the code to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are asking for, but I do see that your main col-xs-8 and col-xs-3 do not add up to 12.  I would make your sidebar col-xs-4 because you have an unfilled column which might be creating the margin problem on the right side.

Comment: Ah. I seem to have had a basic misunderstanding of that detail. Thanks, for the tip.